# structuremap auto registration working ONLY for types in theCAllingAssembly

Tags: structuremap

i'm trying to get auto registration to work for assemblies added to the Scan operation. Currently only the types in the current assembly are being registered - any types that are added to the scan do not get registered automatically (i have to add them by hand).

I know the assembly is getting pulled in because i have a Registry class within the assembly containing LogService whose types are getting registered.

Is there some switch i'm missing or other simple reason why this doesnt work??

I'm using version 2.6.4.1

### thanks for any help

this is my scan. I want all the types to be autoregistered that live in the assembly containing LogService:

```
scan =>
{
scan.TheCallingAssembly();
scan.AssemblyContainingType< LogService >();
scan.LookForRegistries();
scan.WithDefaultConventions();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure which assemblies are included in StructureMap auto-registration by using the `Assembly` method of the `IAssemblyScanner`.  Documentation is available at http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm

**Update**  It seems like you've got the right idea.  The part your missing is where you register each previously loaded assembly.  You can get these from the `AppDomain`, by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.  You should be able to figure out the rest without difficulty

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am referring to the documentation there. I am using AssemblyContainingType to include the assembly but that is not working.

Comment: thanks, but I thought that AssemblyContainingType does the assembly registration. If i do get a handle to the actual assembly, then how do i register it in structureMap?

Comment: There is a method named `Assembly`, which takes an `Assembly` object as its single parameter.  If the `AssemblyContainingType` method doesn't work, you might want to make sure the target assembly is loaded at the point when you execute your registration.

Comment: I figured it out, my interface and class were not by convention, the interface name was IItest and the class was test. Spelling mistake :(